# How to make route method works in Play 2.x sub-project?

Tags: scala, testing, routes, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.3 project with a [sub-project](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTSubProjects) inside. Following this [tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest), I am writing a test for sub-project's controller with `route` method:

```
"Get Action" in new WithApplication {
  val Some(result) = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/sub/bob/11"))

  status(result) mustEqual OK
}
```

Assumed in routes.conf, the sub-project routes is configured like this:

```
->  /sub    sub.Routes
```

And in sub.Routes, it contains:

```
GET  /bob/:id    controllers.sub.BobController.get(id: Int)
```

However the `route()` method always returns `None`. Using `route(FakeRequest(GET, "/bob/11"))` doesn't work too.

Currently I can only solve the problem by direct call to the Controller's method:

```
val result = BobController.get(11)(FakeRequest(GET, "/bob/11"))
```

In this case, the "11" parameter in the "/bob/11" become useless as it's unused.

So anyone know how to make the route() works for sub-project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting **application.router** of FakeApplication to submodule's route file.

For example:

```
class SubModuleRouteSpec extends PlaySpecification with After {
  lazy val app = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map("application.router" -> "sub.Routes"))

  "SubModule route" should {

    "Get Action" in new WithApplication(app) {
      val result = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/bob/11")).get
      println(contentAsString(result))
      result must not beNull
    }
  }

  override def after: Any = Play.stop()
}
```

Comment: But why need of `Play.stop()` ?

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry, in this example you can just ignore it. If you need to create a fresh new FakeApplication for every test case (Get Action 1, Get Action 2, Get Action 3 and so on..) then you may use Play.stop() to cleanout the resources.

Comment: I've tried with two "Get Action" blocks and I got `IllegalStateException: : The play Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)`. Here is the solution: https://gist.github.com/ian-kent/9037719. So the `app` should be `val app = () => FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map("application.router" -> "sub.Routes"))`, and thus `new WithApplication(app())`.

Comment: Also the use of `After` is wrong. For class level, you should use `AfterExample` instead. However I find out `Play.stop()` is not necessary anymore after applying the fix as each test block use their own FakeApplication instance and the instance will stop by itself after each test block is done.